# Нахождение закономерности среди элементов строкового массива в C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Нужно реализовать алгоритм для нахождения закономерностей у элементов строкового массива. Если какой-то символ в слове попадается более чем половине слов, то он записывается в ответ, иначе ставиться "-".
Например: массив (ABBACG, ABCCCB, BCBADG, ACCBDG, ACCACG, BCBACC)
после обработки алгоритмом должна получиться строка AC-ACG

Comment: Вам что, реализовать алгоритм?

Comment: Да, нужно реализовать этот алгоритм.

Comment: ваш алгоритм не ясен. Как у вас получилась строка `AC-ACG`? Почему в ней A и C повторяются? У вас используется 5 символов - `ABCDG` - где прочерки для символов `BDG`?

Comment: @tym32167 Слова из массива можно мысленно подставить в столбик ровно друг под друга. Потом смотрим: если одна буква повторяется больше половины раз, то она записывается в ответ, иначе ставиться "-"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно прогуляться по каждому индексу каждого слова, собрать статистику и сложить в результат.

Например

```
var words = new[] {"ABBACG", "ABCCCB", "BCBADG", "ACCBDG", "ACCACG", "BCBACC"}; 
var maxLen = words.Max(x=>x.Length);
var sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int i=0; i<maxLen; i++)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();

    for(int j=0; j<words.Length; j++)
    {
        if (i >= words[j].Length) continue;
        var c = words[j][i];
        if (dict.ContainsKey(c)) dict[c]++;
        else dict[c]=1;
    }

    var toInsert = '-';
    foreach(var kv in dict)
    {
        if (kv.Value > (maxLen / 2))
        {
            toInsert = kv.Key;
            break;
        }
    }

    sb.Append(toInsert);
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Вывод

```
AC-ACG
```

**UPD**

Решение с использованием [алгоритма Бойера-Мура](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0) из [соседнего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1005200/179763). По скорости работы это то же самое, что первый вариант, но по потреблению памяти будет оптимальней.

```
var words = new[] { "ABBACG", "ABCCCB", "BCBADG", "ACCBDG", "ACCACG", "BCBACC" };
var maxLen = words.Max(x => x.Length);
var sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < maxLen; i++)
{
    char major = '-';
    var count = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < words.Length; j++)
    {
        if (i >= words[j].Length) continue;
        var c = words[j][i];

        if (count == 0)
        {
            major = c;
            count++;
        }
        else if (c == major) count++;
        else count--;
    }

    count = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < words.Length; j++)
        if (i < words[j].Length)
            if (major == words[j][i]) count++;

    if (count > (maxLen / 2))
        sb.Append(major);
    else
        sb.Append('-');
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Вывод

```
AC-ACG
```

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение - могу предположить, что инструктор не против увидеть вычисление доминирующих элементов (majority element) с помощью линейного [алгоритма Бойера-Мура](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)  (это не тот, что подстроки ищет)

Пример реализации на Delphi (символы строк нумеруются с единицы, строки мутабельны, подразумевается, что строи одной длины) выдаёт `AC-ACG`

```
function MostCommons(lst: TArray<string>): string;
  var
    len, i, j, half: Integer;
    Counter: TArray<Integer>;
    Sample: string;
  begin
    len := Length(lst[0]);
    Sample := lst[0];
    SetLength(Counter, len + 1);
    for j := 1 to len do
      Counter[j] := 1;

    for i := 0 to High(lst) do begin
      for j := 1 to len do
        if Sample[j] = lst[i][j] then
          Counter[j] := Counter[j] + 1
        else begin
          if Counter[j] > 1 then
            Counter[j] := Counter[j] - 1
          else begin
            Sample[j] := lst[i][j];
            Counter[j] := 1;
          end;
        end;
    end;

    for j := 1 to len do
      Counter[j] := 0;
    for i := 0 to High(lst) do
      for j := 1 to len do
        if lst[i][j] = Sample[j] then
          Inc(Counter[j]);

    half := (Length(lst) + 2) div 2;
    for j := 1 to len do
      if Counter[j] < half then
        Sample[j] := '-';

    Result := Sample;
  end;
```

Comment: Сорри, я не удержался и запилил версию с этим алгоритмом :) Так что с меня вам плюсик.

Comment: Ага, Вы обратный порядок циклов использовали, чтобы одним счётчиком обойтись и строки посимвольно строить билдером. Ну я уже Ваш ответ плюсовал, больше не могу ;)